# Error creating subscription on ActiveMQ with Stompest Python

Tags: python, activemq-artemis

I encounter some error while I try to make a consumer on ActiveMQ with Stompest. Here is the error:

```
stompest.error.StompProtocolError: Cannot handle command: ERROR [expected=MESSAGE, headers={'content-length': '43', 'content-type': 'text/plain', 'message': 'AMQ339016 Error creating subscription clientid'}]
```

```
AMQ339016 Error creating subscription clientid01
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: What STOMP frame are you sending to trigger this?

Comment: Also, did the `ERROR` frame have a body? If so, what was it?